# disabling filesystem journaling on EXT4

Tags: fstab

just wanted to know other than the obvious data integrity 
does removing data journaling retain the filesystem as EXT4 ? 
i read somewhere that without journaling the filesystem reverts to EXT2/3

also how nobarriers / barriers = 0 disable journaling?

Comment: `barrier=0` does not disable journaling...?

Comment: sorry let me re-phrase that when partitions are mounted with nobarriers this effectively disables write-caching, however with journaling disabled, does this make nobarriers obsolete? does it only take affect if journaling is enabled?